# Calling get_header() with installed FSE theme

Tags: plugin-development, full-site-editing

I'm working on a plugin that adds a custom WP rewrite rule using `add_rewrite_rule()` and I'm loading a custom template for that rule using `template_include` hook and passing the template path to that hook, so when the user visits that URL, the template is rendered successfully.
The template itself contains `get_header()` on the top and `get_footer()` at the bottom, and they are working as expected.

The problem comes when I install **Full Site Editing** themes like '**twenty twenty three**', and I see this errors:

```
Deprecated: File Theme without header.php is deprecated since version 3.0.0 with no alternative available. Please include a header.php template in your theme. in /path/to/wp_installation/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5583
```

```
Deprecated: File Theme without footer.php is deprecated since version 3.0.0 with no alternative available. Please include a footer.php template in your theme. in /path/to/wp_installation/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5583
```

I know that the FSE themes are blocks, so how can I load the header block and the footer block?
Also, I want to know how to check if the active theme is FSE theme or not.

**Update 1**

I tried to create a custom page template and used `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions inside that template, and it raises the same errors.

**Update 2**

I found that this is related to this [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/55023) on WordPress core trac.